# pyglet - render sprites in order, depending on y value, using batches

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, pyglet

I am coding a game (2D) using pyglet, and have encountered a problem - I need to draw sprites to the screen in order of their y-value, using a single batch. This is to achieve the perception of depth, e.g. objects with a higher y-value (meaning they are higher up the screen) should be drawn first; drawing top down; drawing highest to lowest.

I have a dictionary of classes (in no particular order), and a list of the same classes, sorted in order of each class's y-value. This list is generated every time the screen is drawn. Each class contains the object's sprite, coordinates etc. as attributes. All of the sprites are on the same batch.

I have looked at options such as OrderedGroups, yet this appears to not be the best choice - I may need an undefined number of groups (they would need to be generated on the fly?). I cannot find many relevant examples on how this would be implemented in the way I require.

Example of what I want to achieve, but using a potentially infinite number of layers:

[image: http://html.net/tutorials/css/figure020.gif]

Comment: Sprites can be grouped in `OrderedGroup` and `Batch`, one batch per Y value. And they should never be re-created unless the `Y` position changes. But if so, you should change that class/prites `batch` property. Each `z-index` is a new batch and orderedgroup. Is there a particular reason why this isn't working?

Comment: Surely having a batch/group for every single y level would make using batches redundant. To mitigate the problem, I have just dropped batches from my program, and draw each sprite individually, in order of Y. I also found this forum post, which suggests that what I'm trying to achieve is in fact impossible: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyglet-users/cEiChP86cvo

Comment: Usually sprites isn't 1 pixel high. So batches makes sense because you don't have to render each individual pixel/sprite one by one. Instead you do `batchX.draw()` and that saves you `X` ammount of pixels per `Y` level of drawing. What you're asking is very unclear, I honestly have no idea why this would be impossible seeing as I've done something similar to what you describe many times.. Could you draw a picture or show a screenshot of what you want with manual sprite rendering?

Comment: @Torxed https://imgur.com/a/fHG0z this shows the effect i want to achieve with batches. like depth - things that are further away appear behind closer objects. the problem was that i need an un-predetermined number of layers

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I wanting to render probably several sets of a hundred sprites layered up close together and even a batch of just 1 "tower" of 255 30x30px sprites (all slightly offset) is extremely slow compared to say 25 and they are rendered out of order. Perhaps I should turn them into vertices with textures thereby allowing manual z-ordering with actual coordinates? Seems a little overkill and far more work. 
I was hoping to achieve something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjFlIxGzABY)

Comment: @ch4rl1e97 no I never solved this or found an alternative